# Automatically generate dynamic Sitemap.xml for Nuxt VueJs Firestore App

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, sitemap, nuxt.js

I have a site similar to Stackoverflow where users can create a post (or question) which gets its own URL and should be SEO optimized. Therefore I need to include these dynamic pages in my SiteMap.xml. I would like to find an automatic way to insert each dynamic URL to my Sitemap when initially created.

Hoping to not reinvent the wheel, I found [sitemap-module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/sitemap-module) for nuxt, however the example they use for dynamic pages is statically written, so not sure what good that does.

I am having a hard time even conceptualizing how to set this up and what is possible with current infrastructure. Can Firestore functions update source code and redeploy or are there any firestore hosting features to help? Could/ should I set up a cron job to run every night to first run a script to query firestore and update sitemap file on local computer, then automatically deploy it to firestore from command line? Any script examples?

Tech used: VueJS, Node.js, Nuxt/ SSR, Firestore (db and hosting), and Express

Comment: I'm the author of "sitemap-module". You can add dynamic pages with the `routes` option + a promise call (see eg. https://github.com/nuxt-community/sitemap-module#function-which-returns-a-promise). You only have to create an API that expose your page data for sitemap with a `serverMiddleware` of Nuxt.

Comment: @NicolasPennec thanks, I saw that but was confused with the dynamic section directly above it hardcoding userids in route. So ignore that and the axios call in promise is to api express endpoint? How does it work there? I query all userids from firestore and return in res I guess? This would update sitemap every time I build and deploy? Hopefully having multiple level URL dynamic params would work as well with a few tweaks?

Comment: Look at nuxt-pwa

Comment: Check out my [blog post](https://elision.design/en/blog/dynamic-routes-in-sitemap-with-nuxt-js) for a conceptual inspiration. We also needed to fetch all available pages and generate the sitemap based on it. Keep in mind that It's not a "one way to solve them all" approach, but more of a possible methodological illustration.

Comment: Hi there, working with a very similar stack, wondering what was your approach towards this?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it. Hope this helps. Please share if you managed to get a different solution.
I used `npm install @nuxtjs/sitemap`

Website here - [@nuxtjs/sitemap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/sitemap)

In nuxt.config.js

```
var routes = []
var allUsers = [{'username': 'username'}] // Getting users as an Array
for (var i = 0; i < allUsers.length; i++) {
  routeObject = {
    'url': '/profile/' + allUsers[i].username
  }
  routes.push(routeObject);
}
module.exports = {
  sitemap: {
    path: '/sitemap.xml',
    hostname: 'Your hostname here',
    cacheTime: 1000 * 60 * 15,
    gzip: true,
    generate: false, 
    routes: routes
  }
}
```